# Get Discord Avatar + Username and post it on Website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, discord

I am working on my website and I wanted to ask, how can I fetch my own Avatar + Username so it will display on my website since I change my username often and I don't have to edit the website manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to the [Discord Developer Portal documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user) you have to run a `fetch` request on the discord API and get self user using the `https://discord.com/api/v9/users/${user.id}` **or** the `https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me` endpoint.

Example:
https://discord.com/api/v9/users/603948445362946084 - Hey look that's me!

```json
    {
      "id": "603948445362946084",
      "username": "0_0",
      "discriminator": "6666",
      "avatar": "redacted",
      "verified": true,
      "email": "*********@*****.com",
      "flags": 717,
      "banner": "redacted",
      "accent_color": 16711680,
      "premium_type": 2,
      "public_flags": 717
    }
```

It would return a parsed JSON response with the user data.